# Arduino Serial.print(, BIN) odd behavior

Tags: c++, arduino

Code:

```
char a = 0x70;
char b = 0x80;

Serial.println(a, BIN); // Should print  1110000
Serial.println(b, BIN); // Should print 10000000
```

Output:

```
1110000
11111111111111111111111110000000
```

I know this has something to do with the first bit being one makes it a negative number and maybe it tries to print it as an `int` by default? Making the `char` `unsigned` does not change this, however.

Comment: Can you assign a variable to that println (yeah, println() actually returns something: http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Println)?

Comment: also, what if you cast it beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

This is inspired by @Ben's comments on the question. It appears that `Serial.println((unsigned char)b, BIN);` gets the desired output.

Here is my complete sketch:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Confirm observations from question
  char a = 0x70;
  char b = 0x80;

  long aPrint = Serial.println(a, BIN); // Should print  1110000
  long bPrint = Serial.println(b, BIN); // Should print 10000000

  // Output println results (Ben comment #1)
  Serial.print("aPrint: ");
  Serial.println(aPrint);
  Serial.print("bPrint: ");
  Serial.println(bPrint);

  // Explicit cast from char
  Serial.print("(int)b: ");
  Serial.println((int)b);

  // Via unsigned char
  Serial.print("(unsigned char)b: ");
  Serial.println((unsigned char)b);
  // And print in binary
  Serial.println((unsigned char)b, BIN);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Output:

```
1110000
11111111111111111111111110000000
aPrint: 9
bPrint: 34
(int)b: -128
(unsigned char)b: 128
10000000
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` appears to be a signed type on your machine.  That means when yout pass it to `println`, which expects an `int`, it gets [sign-extended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) to the value you see there.  Use a cast as suggested in other answers or switch to `unsigned char`.

Edit:  I noticed your post says that using `unsigned` doesn't help.  That might indicate that the API is doing something funny internally.